# How can I get anki to display images on the backs of cards? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: anki

[image: edited card to add a picture on the back]

[image: when card is displayed, the image is not shown]

I can't figure out how to get an image to display on the back of a card.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with anki as well and the described process is working fine. It looks like you customized the card layout further than only renaming Front Side to Deutsch and Back Side to Englisch. It should work if you just use the default layout.